# how to fetch battery status with hours,minutes and seconds in IOS?

Tags: ios, batterymanager

How to display battery status in uilabels (hours ,minutes and seconds) (03:49:33) . when battery dying decrease the time. how to check battery status

Comment: you can estimate using the `batteryLevel` value and the official estimation of battery's uptime on the current device, based on what progress your app is doing (e.g. video or audio-playback, etc...), what kinda services are on (e.g. wifi, bluetooth, etc...), the brightness of the screen; or just simple use the battery changes differences in a unit of time and make the estimation based on that – spoiler: none of them will be deadly accurate but it is a good estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true
```

Then you can create a computed property to return the battery level:

```
var batteryLevel: Float {

    return UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
}
```

Swift 3

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

var batteryLevel: Float {

    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
}
```

Comment: its only displaying percentage . how to show value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you check the battery status,

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

var batteryLevel: Float {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
}
```

Comment: its displaying percentage bro.

Comment: you have to convert that percent into time